# Merge Sort Base Case (Recursion) Dissect

Tags: c, mergesort

From the book Robert Sedgewick & Kevin Wayne Algorithms 4th Edition

In recursion part base case code is

```
if(end <= start)
    {
        return;
    }
```

But I've checked `end` never become lower than the `start` index. only `end = start` happen when there's only 1 element left. Then why `<=` less than operator is used where only one condition that is equal `=` works all the time?

Suppose an array `a[8,5,3]` is taken.

Now the middle point is 1st index so after divide

```
a[8,5] and a[3]
```

> `divide(a,0,1) and divide(a,2,2), merge(a,0,1,2)`
>   start is smaller than end in `divide(a,0,1)` and `start=end` happen in `divide(a,2,2)` function call.

Now mid is 0th index.

```
a[8] and a[5]
```

> `divide(a,0,0) and divide(a,1,1), merge(a,0,0,1)`
>   here in both function call `start=end` is only true.

so literally `end` never became smaller than `start` thus `end<start` never happen. only `end=start` happen.

can anyone explain me why do we use the < (less than) operator in base case of merge sort?

Full Recursive Code

```
int divide(int a[], int start, int end)
{
    int mid;

    if(end<=start)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        mid = (start+end)/2;
        divide(a, start, mid);
        divide(a, mid+1, end);
        merge(a, start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have your condition like `if (end = start)`? not `if (end == start)`?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad, thanx mate! yeah it works if I write `(end == start)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that the `divide` function **never** calls itself with arguments so that `end < start`. So therefore the if-statement could just as well be `if (end == start)`.

Maybe it's to catch if the divide function is called from **another** piece of code in an incorrect way, e.g.

```
void foo(int a[]) 
{ 
    divide(a, 5, 3);
}
```

That would cause an infinit loop if your check only was `==` instead of `<=`. Therefor it seems more safe to use `<=`.

The original code could also be rewritten like:

```
int divide(int a[], int start, int end)
{
    int mid;

    if(end > start)
    {
        mid = (start+end)/2;
        divide(a, start, mid);
        divide(a, mid+1, end);
        merge(a, start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

In any case it probably doesn't matter for performance - an optimizing compiler will re-arrange things anyway.

> BTW: Notice that your function is said to return an int but you don't do that. Maybe you really want it to be: void divide(.....)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the mistake I've done with void.

Comment: can you please explain how come it will be infinity loop in this code? 

`void foo(int a[]) 
{ 
    divide(a, 5, 3);
}`

Comment: @Michel If you use `==` instead of `<=` the call `divide(a, 5, 3)` will cause an infinite loop because: The first time `mid` becomes 4 (i.e. (5+3)/2). Then the function calls itself using `divide(a, 5, 4)`. This time `mid` becomes 4 (i.e. (5+4)/2). Then the function calls itself using `divide(a, 5, 4)`. The same call again! So this will go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

you could write recursive part of the function divide as below

```
void divide(int a[], int start, int end)
{
    int mid;

    if(start < end)
    {
        mid = (start+end)/2;
        divide(a, start, mid);
        divide(a, mid+1, end);
        merge(a, start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same code as in the @4386427's answer except the return type being `void` or changing `end > start` to `start < end`, which btw is same.

Comment: You should leave a comment to the answer if you think that the return type should be `void` instead of posting a new answer with the exact same code in it.

Comment: Hmm you are right! Basically same as I followed the pseudo code from Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen

Comment: I tried to comment but stackoverflow said I need 50 reps to comment! @MuhammadAhmad